# Flutter Socket.IO cannot connect to server, but browser works fine

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, socket.io, backend

Was going to use Socket.IO for authorizing in a flutter application, but it wont work on anything other than localhost:

```
String serverURL = "https://example.awsapprunner.com";
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('$serverURL/client', <String, dynamic>{'transports': ['websocket']});

checkUserExists(String phoneNum, context) {
  socket.connect();
  socket.emit('login', phoneNum);

  socket.on('login_error', (res)=> {
    log("new user"),
  });

  socket.on('session-started',(sid)=>{
    log("old user!"),
  });
}
```

The app won't even connect to the socket so anything after socket.connent() never runs.

Here's what I have tried

- 'autoConnect': true
- replacing 'https' with 'wss' or 'ws'
- removing 'https://' altogether
- Different Cloud Services (AWS, GC, Azure)
- local server (works and connects perfectly fine)
- connecting to the server via browser (also works perfectly fine)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dart, an update was made and now you can replace wss with https:

```
socket = IO.io(
     "https://url.com",
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .setPath("/io")
          .setReconnectionAttempts(5)
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .build(),
    );
```